# How to add SSL and HTTPS to HttpListener

Tags: c#, .net, http, ssl

I am currently struggling with adding SSL and HTTPS to my .NET server. This I say current main method:

```
static async Task Main()
        {
            var dbContext = new DatabaseContext();
            var databaseService = new DatabaseService(dbContext);

            HttpListener listener = new()
            {
                AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.None,
                Prefixes = { "https://*:8080/", "http://*:8083/" }
            };

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2("./localhost.pem");

            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Listening for HTTP and HTTPS connections...");

            while (true)
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("got it");

                if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
                {
                    await WebSocketRequest.ProcessWebSocketRequest(context, databaseService);
                } else
                {
                    if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                    {
                        await WriteResponse.WriteOptionsResponse(context);
                    } else
                    {
                        await HttpRequests.ProcessRestRequest(context, databaseService);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I made the certificate with mkcert `mkcert localhost`, and added it to build dir. I can print the data, so loading it does not seem to be the issue.
But requests are not being made to the server from neither React nor Postman. Http requests to 8083 works fine, only HTTPS to 8080 fails. Postman gives `ECONNRESET` error, and React says `Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.`

**Update**
Thanks for all answers. Ended up switching to ASP.Net

Comment: You really should be using ASP.NET for this.

Comment: Ensure that your server supports modern SSL/TLS protocols. Some clients might fail to connect if the server only supports outdated protocols. You can try enabling support for TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3.

Comment: Just use ASP.NET for this. HttpListener is internal guts, which shouldn't be used explicitly. You leave yourself to so much hard problems like security/testability/recovery/etc, not to mention anyone looking at your code will get seizures.

Comment: `Prefixes = { "https://*:8080/", "http://*:8083/" }` you can't use a wildcard for HTTPS as it depends on a proper hostname to verify.  See the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-net-httplistener Also missing a bunch of `using`s to dispose everything correctly.